# How to compile and run any file at any location in C,java and C++?

Tags: java, compilation

I am creating a editor kind of application where I want to compile and run (of course create, edit, open also) C,C++ and Java files;
I am creating it in Java.

Now for compilation and running I am taking the whole path of file
and compiling & running via this full path.

for eg.

```
 compileFileCommand = javac /media/disk/eclipse/\/UniversalIDE/Java/FirstJava.java

try
{
    System.out.println("Compiling Java File");
    Process compileProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(compileFileCommand);
            compileProcess.waitFor();
    String line = "";
    BufferedReader bri = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(compileProcess.getInputStream()));
    BufferedReader bre = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(compileProcess.getErrorStream()));
    while ((line = bri.readLine()) != null)
    {
     System.out.println(line);
    }
    bri.close();
    while ((line = bre.readLine()) != null)
    {
     System.out.println(line);
    }
    bre.close();
    compileProcess.waitFor();
    System.out.println("Done Java Compile.");
} catch (Exception e)
{
 // TODO: handle exception
 System.out.println("Exception in Java Compile. ");
 System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

Above code works fine and create a class file at location of java file.But bri.readLine() always contains null.

For running Java file

```
runFileCommand = java /media/disk/eclipse/\/UniversalIDE/Java/FirstJava
```

And for running C & CPP files the same procedure

For C compilation

```
String compileFileCommand = "gcc " + fileNameWithFullPath;
```

For C Running

```
String runFileCommand = "./" + fileNameWithFullPath.split(".c")[0];
```

For CPP compilation

```
String compileFileCommand = "g++ " + fileNameWithFullPath;
```

For CPP Running

```
String runFileCommand = "./" + fileNameWithFullPath.split(".cpp")[0];
```

I use the same code as used for compiling java file but it does not give anything as result and bri.readLine() gives null all the time.

Please help me to solve this problem and please give me any suggestion on my application.

Comment: If you have too many errors and the buffer fills , the compiler will stop as you don't read the errors until the program finishes i.e. you have a deadlock.  I would print errors to System.err.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default output filename from gcc and g++ is `a.out`, not input filename without extension.

Try `runFileCommand = "./a.out"`, or use the `-o` option with gcc/g++ to specify output filename.

Also none of the compilation commands output anything when there's no errors or warnings.

Answer (score 0):

`bri.readLine()` returns null because when a Java file compiles without error, nothing is printed to standard out.  Was that the question?